# Set an item position in the view programmatically with the x and y coordinates

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageButton and I would like to set its position programmatically to x and y.

How can I do this? I read something abaut setTop() and setLeft() but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
         int width, int height, int x, int y);
params.x=30;
params.y=50;

imageButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

using this code you can position you item in absolute (x,y) coordinate in your view, but you need to use you main root layout AbsoluteLayout otherwise it throws error.

But AbsoluteLayout is depreciated in latest version so avoid that , try to use RelativeLayout

Comment: Thank you, but in relative layout, there is no params.x and params.y.

If I understand, I shuld use a absoluteLayout and thec call the AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams?

Comment: ya you should use Absolute layout if you going to positioning using x & y coordonates